# Выборка таблицы по ID таблицы другой?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Есть таблица

```
___User______                  ____Group_____
user_id  ------------|         data_id_grou
name                 |_________id_user_id
password                       name
```

GroupEntity.java

```
...

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id_user")
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
    ...
```

UserEntity.java

```
...  
private long id_album;
    ...
    @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "id_user")
        protected long getId_user() {
            return id_user;
        }
    ...
```

Мне надо получить список вех групп в которых есть определнный User. в DAO поиск, создание и прочее всё делается отлично. Но такую выборку в hibernate не знаю как сделать

Comment: Похоже на JPA, тогда например так `em.createQuery("SELECT g FROM GroupEntity g WHERE g.user = :user").setParameter("user", user).getResultList();` где em - Ваш EntityManager, user - это user

Comment: Точно в Ваших группах только один юзер?

Comment: Добавьте информации о том чем вы именно пользуетесь для DAO и вам обязательно помогут. Скорее всего это можно либо решить немного вычурной Criteria, либо с помощью одного запроса на HQL.

Answer (score 1):

Если DAO у вас построены на `Criteria`, то нужно смотреть в сторону `Subqueries` и `DetachedCriteria`.